# Tracking Displayed Admob URLs

Tags: android, admob, ads, wireshark, google-ads-api

I am trying to passively record all ad banners displayed in an app. I am able to leave my phone alone and have a program to run to grab all the screen shots. However the URL data is rarely presented in the banner itself.

I need to be able to track all traffic and match the URL (hopefully with a timestamp) to the ad banner (to which I already have a timestamp).

I have used Eclipse in debug mode, Netwitnes and Wireshark. In all of that traffic I have been  unable to track a URL displayed in an ad banner.

Any ideas on how to track this?

Comment: Can you attach one of wireshark captures?

Comment: It's just a typical wireshark capture while running an app like Angry Birds. I won't through one in since my PII can be found, but it's simple to replicate my capture. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've arrived at two solutions. One is implemented one is a Work In Progress.

The first utilizes [BlueStacks](http://bluestacks.com/), DDMS ([Logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html)) and [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). I set up the bluestack emulator with an app running ads. I recorded a macro with AutoHotkey and let it run. When I want to monitor it I will take a look at the logcat log via DDMS to find the urls for the ads I want. It's sort of a round about way but it works. Idealing I would like to write a [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) script to do all of this. I know the capabilities exists but actually installing and setting up that tool has proven difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[Bro](http://www.bro-ids.org) makes it really easy to extract URLs from a network trace:

```
bro -r trace.pcap
bro-cut ts host uri < http.log | awk '{ print $1, $2 $3 }'
```

The small tool `bro-cut` ships with Bro and extracts the relevant (typed) columns from the log. In this case, you want the timestamp (`ts`) plus the URL components (`host` and `uri`). Some example output:

```
1258535653.087137 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab?0911180916
1258535655.525107 www.update.microsoft.com/v9/windowsupdate/selfupdate/wuident.cab?0911180916
1258535656.495997 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/a/selfupdate/WSUS3/x86/Other/wsus3setup.cab?0911180916
1258535656.548965 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/a/selfupdate/WSUS3/x86/Other/wsus3setup.cab?0911180916
1258535658.736840 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab?0911180916
1258535666.171669 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab?0911180916
1258535698.141338 212.227.97.133/rpc.html?e=bl
1258535656.548965 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/a/selfupdate/WSUS3/x86/Other/wsus3setup.cab?0911180916
1258535658.736840 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab?0911180916
1258535666.171669 download.windowsupdate.com/v9/windowsupdate/redir/muv4wuredir.cab?0911180916
1258535698.141338 212.227.97.133/rpc.html?e=bl
1258535699.032780 87.106.1.47/rpc.html?e=bl
1258535699.931215 87.106.1.89/rpc.html?e=bl
```

What remains is filtering out the Admob URLs, which you probably know best how to do.